# Merge or zip different list of objects having different structures into single list

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, generics

Hi all i have three classes like this as below

```
class A 
{
    public int number{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
}
class B
{
   public string casted{get; set;}
}
class C
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public bool isSelect {get; set;}
}
```

and i have data format like this

```
var aObject = new A () { number = 11, name = "John" };
var aObject2= new A () { number = 22, name = "Steve" }; 

IList<A> ListA= new List<A>(){ aObject,aObject2 };

var bObject1 = new B () { casted = "test" };
var bObject2 = new B () { casted = "test1" };
var bObject3 = new B () { casted = "test2" };

IList<B> ListB = new List<B>(){ bObject1 , bObject2 ,bObject3 };

var cObject = new C() { Id = "1", isSelect = true };
var cObject2 = new C(){ Id = "2", isSelect = false };

IList<C> ListC = new List<C>() { cObject ,cObject2 };
```

All are having different structure and i will be getting data in list of above classes like `List<A>, List<B> and List<C>`

I am looking to form a data kind of structure below with these three lists merged into single one like as below

I am looking for result list looks like as below.

**Result** :

```
Number    name    casted    Id    isSelect
 11       john    test      1     true
 22       Steve   test1     2     false
  -        -      test2     -       -
```

Is there any way i can achieve this kind of result object, I know if you have same structure we can concatenate the list but here i have different structure.

Could any one please let me know any ideas on how to do achieve this that would be very grateful to me Many thanks in advance

Comment: What logic decides that this row is valid: `1       john    test      1     true` but not this `2       Steve    test      2     false`? is it just by order?

Comment: it is just by order only and in each list we need to go through the order and concatenate the items

Comment: It seems, that you'll need something like union type, which will added in [future versions of C#](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Addition after comment:** in the while part of my code I forgot to MoveNext. Repaired. Thanks `enigma state` for noticing.

So you have three sequences of different items, and you want a method, that returns a sequence containing the same indexed elements of your sequences.

This is a difficult way to say, that you want a sequence like:

```
A[0] / B[0] / C[0]
A[1] / B[1] / C[1]
A[2] / null / C[2] 
etc.
```

So if one of the sequences runs out of elements, you want to continue enumerating using  NULL as value

This method is very similar to [Enumerable.Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8), except that you have three sequences, and you want to continue enumerating if one of the sequences is too short.

> Whenever you think there is a missing LINQ method, consider writing an extension method for IEnumerable. Especially if you think you can reuse it in other situations

Creating an extension method for an IEnumerable is usually fairly simple. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

I'll write a generic extension method, that has three input sequences, and a result selector to define the returned output sequence. This result selector is similar to the selector parameter in Enumerable.Select.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipWithNull<T1, T2, T2, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<T1> source1,
    IEnumerable<T2> source2,
    IEnumerable<T3> source3,
    Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    // get the enumerators and start enumerating until there are no more elements
    IEnumerator<T1> enumerator1 = source1.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T2> enumerator2 = source2.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T3> enumerator3 = source3.GetEnumerator();

    // check if there is at least one item available
    bool t1Available = enumerator1.MoveNext();
    bool t2Available = enumerator2.MoveNext();
    bool t3Available = enumerator3.MoveNext();
    bool anyAvailabe = t1Available || t2Available || t3Available;

    while (anyAvailable)
    {
        // if available use the Current, else use default (= null for classes)
        T1 t1 = t1Available ? enumerator1.Current ?? default(T1);
        T2 t2 = t2Available ? enumerator2.Current ?? default(T2);
        T3 t3 = t3Available ? enumerator3.Current ?? default(T3);

        TResult result = resultSelector(t1, t2, t3);
        yield return result;

        t1Available = enumerator1.MoveNext();
        t2Available = enumerator2.MoveNext();
        t3Available = enumerator3.MoveNext();
        anyAvailabe = t1Available || t2Available || t3Available;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<A> listA = ...
List<B> listA = ...
List<C> listA = ...

// you want a dash if the value is null
const string dash = "-";

var result = listA.ZipWithNull(listB, listC,

    // parameter ResultSelector: taks one a, b, c and create the output:
    (a, b, c) => new
    {
        Number = a?.Number.ToString() ?? dash,
        Name = a?.Name ?? dash,
        Casted = b?.Casted ?? dash,
        Id = c?.Id.ToString() ?? dash,
        IsSelect = c?.IsSelect.ToString() ?? dash,
    });
```

Do note that this result selector can be optimized. For instance, whether parameter `a` equals null is checked twice. With a little more effort you can make sure that every input of the resultSelector is checked only once. For the example I chose simplicity above efficiency.

The nice thing is that you can use `ZipWithNull` for any sequence that you want to zip with null values as substitute. Because I created ZipWithNull as any other LINQ method, I can intertwine it with other LINQ methods:

```
var result = customers
    .Where(customer => customer.BirthDay.Year >= 2000)
    .ZipWithNull(
         addresses.Where(address => address.City == "Amsterdam"),
         orders.Where(order => order.Total > 1000,
         (customer, address, order) => new {...});
    .GroupBy(...)
    .OrderByDescending(...)
    // Etc();
```

Comment: When i am trying to loop through the result using `foreach` like this `foreach (var item in result) {}` it is going through the infinite loop.. i need to process the results for further data manipulation but it is going through the infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

So you have a couple of challenges in that the models you provided don't match the lists you provided (e.g. classes are `A` and `C` not `a` and `c` and `Id` on `C` should be `string` not `int`), but after changing all that we can do sth like this:

```
private static void AddAllValuesToDictionary<T>(List<Dictionary<string, object>> target, IList<T> source) {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++) 
        {
            if (target.Count() <= i) {
               target.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>()); 
            }

            foreach(var prop in properties) {
                target[i][prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(source[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then

```
var result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

AddAllValuesToDictionary(result, ListA);
AddAllValuesToDictionary(result, ListB);
AddAllValuesToDictionary(result, ListC);
```

If you kind of really wanted an object instead of a dictionary, you could go for `ExpandoObject` but then essentially you will get experience reverse to the above.

In my listing, if two objects (e.g. 'A' and 'C') have a duplicate Property Name, the latter will override the former. With `ExpandoObject` the first value you set will be the one that comes in the result.

**Update** Here's an example with `Expando`

Add `using System.Dynamic;` to your file.

Then

```
private static void AddAllValuesToListOfExpandos<T>(List<ExpandoObject> target, IList<T> source) {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Count(); i++) 
        {
            if (target.Count() <= i) {
               target.Add(new ExpandoObject()); 
            }

            foreach(var prop in properties) {
                target[i].TryAdd(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(source[i]));
            }
        }
    }
}

        var result2 = new List<ExpandoObject>();
        AddAllValuesToListOfExpandos(result2, ListA);
        AddAllValuesToListOfExpandos(result2, ListB);
        AddAllValuesToListOfExpandos(result2, ListC);
// Since you're using ExpandoObject you can now use the properties
// the same way you do with dynamic
        Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)result2.First()).casted);
        Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)result2.First()).number);
        Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)result2.Last()).casted);
// note: Next line will fail with RuntimeBinderException
        Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)result2.Last()).number);
```

Comment: these are all creating list of lists where as i need only single list with items combined from those three lists.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to do, but I see 3 ways you could possibly accomplish this.

Most simply, you can create a `List<object>` that contains your data of different classes.
You would then lose the information about what class each object is (you could store these objects in the `List` as `Tuple` with `Type`).

```
List<object> joinedList = new List<object>();
joinedList.AddRange(ListA.Cast<object>());
joinedList.AddRange(ListB.Cast<object>());
joinedList.AddRange(ListC.Cast<object>());
```

Another solution would be to have all of these classes share a base class or interface and construct the `List` of that type.

When reading from the `List` you could check types like `listItem is A`

```
class z
{
}
class a : z
{
    public int number{get; set;}
    public string name{get; set;}
}
class B : z
{
   public string casted{get; set;}
}
class c : z
{
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public bool isSelect {get; set;}
}

List<z> joinedList = new List<z>();
joinedList.AddRange(ListA);
joinedList.AddRange(ListB);
joinedList.AddRange(ListC);
```

You could also create a "joined" version of `A`, `B`, and `C` which might suit your use-case (since it looks like you might be creating a table from the data).

```
class Aggregate
{
   A aData {get;set;}
   B bData {get;set;}
   C cData {get;set;}
}

List<Aggregate> aggregatedData = new List<Aggregate>();
// join your data together into aggregate and add to list
```

Comment: thanks for the input, how can we use aggregate since there is no relationship between three classes to join

Comment: You would either need an identifier on each object that indicates them to be related (e.g. the `Id` on `C` or some other data that describes the relationships (e.g. C.Id of 1 is equivalent to A.Name of John). How were you able to generate the example Result rows in your question? I think you would use the same defining relationship

Comment: I am trying to export document in word and looking to generate a table with sample data i have mentioned and it does not have any relationship

Comment: I am not able to establish the relationship between those classes and is there any other way to get through this